# hi i'm a cs student,i have a little problem

Tags: arrays, c

i have a character array and in outpout when i run the code the terminal delete me some last words
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DIM 90

///PRIMO STEP
void strCAPSLOCK(char stringaMaiusc[DIM]);

///SECONDO STEP
void strMinus(char stringaMinus[DIM]);

///TERZO STEP
void strInvertCaps(char stringaInvert[DIM]);

///QUARTO STEP
void strInitCap(char stringaFirstCaps[DIM]);



int main() {
    char stringa[DIM];

    printf("inserisci stringa\n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s",stringa);
    printf("\nstringa originale : \n %s",stringa);

    /*primo step dell'esercizio,
     * modificare una stringa e convertire
     * i caratteri da minuscolo a maiuscolo*/
     strCAPSLOCK(stringa);

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /*secondo step dell'esercizio,
     * modificare una stringa e convertire
     * i caratteri da maiuscolo a minuscolo*/
     strMinus(stringa);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /*terzo step dell'esercizio,
     * invertire le lettere da minuscolo a maiuscolo*/
    strInvertCaps(stringa);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /*quarto step dell'esercizio,
     * modificare una stringa e convertire
     * la prima lettera di ogni poarola in maiuscolo,
     * tutte le altre lasciarle in minuscolo*/
     strInitCap(stringa);




    return 0;
}

///PRIMO STEP
void strCAPSLOCK(char stringaMaiusc[DIM]){
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<DIM; i++){
        if(stringaMaiusc[i] >= 'a' && stringaMaiusc[i] <= 'z'){
            stringaMaiusc[i] -= 32;
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nla stringa trasformata da minuscola a maiuscola equivale a : \n %s",stringaMaiusc);
}


///SECONDO STEP
void strMinus(char stringaMinus[DIM]){
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < DIM ; ++i) {
        if(stringaMinus[i] >= 'A' && stringaMinus[i] <= 'Z'){
            stringaMinus[i] += 32;
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nla stringa trasformata da maiuscola a minuscola equivale a : \n %s",stringaMinus);
}


///TERZO STEP
void strInvertCaps(char stringaInvert[]){
    int i;
   // int lunghezza_stringa= strlen(stringaInvert);

    for ( i = 0; i < DIM ; ++i) {
        if(stringaInvert[i] >= 'a' && stringaInvert[i] <= 'z'){
            stringaInvert[i+1] -= 32;
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nla stringa che alterna lettere minuscole e maiuscole euivale a : \n %s",stringaInvert);
}


///QUARTO STEP
void strInitCap(char stringaFirstCaps[DIM]){
    int i;
    int j=1;


    for ( i = 0; i < DIM; ++i) {
        if(j && stringaFirstCaps[i]  >= 'a' && stringaFirstCaps[i] <= 'z'){
            stringaFirstCaps[i] -= 32;
            j=0;
        }else if(stringaFirstCaps[i] == ' '){
            j = 1;
        } else if(stringaFirstCaps[i] >= 'A' && stringaFirstCaps[i] <= 'Z'){
            stringaFirstCaps[i] += 32;
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n la stringa che ha come prima lettera di ogni parola maiuscola equivale a : \n %s",stringaFirstCaps);
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

THIS IS THE OUTPOUT

C:\Users\giova\CLionProjects\untitled12\cmake-build-debug\esercitazione_funzioni_stringhe.exe
inserisci stringa      //PRINTF
hi I'm Giovanni and I'm ok, how are you??  //SCANF

stringa originale :      //ORIGINAL ARRAY
hi I'm Giovanni and I'm ok, how are you??

la stringa trasformata da minuscola a maiuscola equivale a :     //FIRST PROCEDURE
HI I'M GIOVANNI AND I'M OK, HOW ARE YOU??

la stringa trasformata da maiuscola a minuscola equivale a :     //SECOND PROCEDURE
hi i'm giovanni and i'm ok, how are you??

la stringa che alterna lettere minuscole e maiuscole euivale a : //THIRD PROCEDURE
hI im

la stringa che ha come prima lettera di ogni parola maiuscola equivale a : //FOURTH PROCEDURE
Hi Im
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Please note that `%[^\n]s` is unusual and is probably a mistake. Format `%[]` is not a subset of `%s`. The two are quite distinct format specifiers.

Comment: By using `DIM` as the iteration limit you are parsing string content that may not have been entered. You should use the *actual* length of the input string. The input may also be breaking the array size (use `scanf(" %89[^\n]",stringa);`). And this `stringaInvert[i+1] -= 32;` **definitely** indexes beyond the array.

Comment: i try...nothing

Comment: i write "%89[^\n] s",stringa and doesn't work

Comment: That is because it should be `scanf(" %89[^\n]", stringa);`. Also please state what you mean by "doesn't work".

Comment: i wrote like you,but the code doesn't work, the terminal delete me some last words

Comment: So did you try fixing the indexing error that's been pointed out in comment and answer?

Comment: i fix that,i delete the [i+1] and i put [i++]

Comment: But now you are incrementing `i` twice.

Comment: like this the code running ok

Comment: If it really is the *next* character that needs to be modified, stop the loop 1 element sooner, for example `for ( i = 0; i < DIM-1; ++i)`

Comment: idk but i can try this conditions on the cicle for.  thank 4 all

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the below line in `///TERZO STEP`:

```cpp
stringaInvert[i+1] -= 32;
```

It is using `i+1`, whereas it should be `i`.

Comment: this procedure is for swap the character from minus to maiusc alternating from one string cell